# MAAS and PXE boot problem

Tags: maas

I have problem with commissioning my nodes because I stuck with this. I add node using CD and node appear in dashboard of server. Then I clicked "accept & commission" then my node boot up and is finally connecting to MaaS server but when it tries to download image then stops like this:

[image]

and nothing happens.

And in dashboard is still commissioning.

[image]

Here is video how its booting : http://youtu.be/jVmQE6SvxmE

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the video, very useful!

I don't think your problem is anything to do with MAAS but I'd be tempted to check that there's no firewall preventing iSCSI access from the node to the server.

Otherwise I would take this to the kernel and/or server people.